# Android: How to customize the label under the launcher icon

Tags: android

The name of my Android app is 14 characters long with no spaces, as such, the full name is not visible on the home screen when displayed under the launcher icon.

I want to use an alternate name for displaying under the launcher icon, so I can break up the name into two strings separated by a space - so that the words should wrap.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modify your res\values\strings.xml to have two strings:

1. app_name_wrappable = "App Name"
2. app_name = "AppName"

Then modify your AndroidManifest.xml (or anywhere else you want the wrapping behavior) to read:

```
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name_wrappable">
```

And leave everything else the same as it is currently.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  He didn't want his title bar changed, just his launcher icon text changed.  Your solution changed both.

Comment: Title bar will get the text from `android:label` so adding other string to string.xml will not solve the issue.

Comment: I figure the way to do it is set the label as mentioned here, then call setTitle in the activity to label each activity specifically

Comment: @Lee: This does not work for me (ics). It only changes the name in the application list (exactly where you probably DON'T want to change it).

Comment: @LuisA.Florit To be honest, they've probably changed how all of this worked in the past two and a half years.  If you have the correct answer, please add it and I'll be happy to give it an upvote and even delete mine.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see the name of your app below the app icon, you should change the `android:label` of the starting activity as the required app name.

Should use `String.xml` for that:

```
 <string name="app_name">YourAppName</string>//Add this code in Strings.xml file
```

Change AndroidManifest.xml as below:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.crm_executive.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score -1):

That text is in your `AndroidManifest.xml` at `android:label`:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

You should change that string to fix your issue.

Comment: Since the manifest uses @string/app_name, you will actually want to change the name in the strings.xml resource file.

Comment: Yes, I tried this, however when I do that it also changes the name that appears in the top of each activity, which up till now had always been the name of the application...so would that mean that I need to manually set a name in each activity to override the default behaviour?

Comment: @johnrock You can use a custom title bar.

Comment: There's no need to write a bunch of code to create a custom title bar when all you need to do is have two separate string resources.