# Creating App Name with subscript not working flutter

Tags: android, flutter

So I want to make my app name as App<sub>5</sub> so I did the following. I went to `andriod/app/src/AndriodManifest.xml` and edited this file to

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

And then went to `andriod/app/src/res/values/strings.xml` and Added my app name as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">App<sub><small>5</small></sub></string>
</resources>
```

But still the subscript isn't working so what did I do wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here your `app_name`'s string is considered to be containing text 'App' and child ***object***  `sub`, that's why it isn't working and you are getting only **App** instead of **App<sub>5</sub>**.

Try instead escaping this `<sub><small>5</small></sub>` by encapsulating it inside `<![CDATA[<sub><small>5</small></sub>]]>` so you will have :

```
<string name="app_name">App<![CDATA[<sub><small>5</small></sub>]]></string>
```

**OR**

using html entities and

```
<string name="app_name">App&lt;sub&gt;&lt;small&gt;5&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/sub&gt;</string>
```

(PS : check if your widget accepts and formats html)

***UPDATE***

> I forgot to add `<` at the beginning and `>` at the end of  `![CDATA[]]`
> , It has been corrected above

In your activity `onCreate` method do like this ( using the app_name above)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        //ADD THIS LINE
        setTitle(Html.fromHtml( getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)));
        ...
    }
```

[image: Title]

Comment: what appears is `App5`  when the first solution App!CDATA[..] is the thing that appeared

Comment: Im testing using an emulator if that makes any difference

Comment: which widget are you using to display app name ?

Comment: Im really sorry im still a newbie but i adjusted the AndriodManifest as i said in the question if u could tell me how i know about this widget

Comment: recopu this `<string name="app_name">App<![CDATA[<sub><small>5</small></sub>]]></string>`
 in **strings.xml**

Comment: thanks for your reply should i update onCreate method for both solutions or second one only

Comment: I did <string name="app_name">App<![CDATA[<sub><small>5</small></sub>]]></string>  and this appeared App<sub>..

Comment: update your **onCreate** method and **strings.xml** with second one

Comment: I think you misunderstood me (Or Im just dumb and didnt express my problem right) what I meant by app name is the name of the app which appears under the icon before opening the app. does this achieve this kind of thing? and if so where can i find onCreate method in flutter

Comment: Sorry even me I misunderstood you...have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125045/android-how-to-customize-the-label-under-the-launcher-icon)